# can't insert special character from java program to oracle 11g database

Tags: java, oracle

i'm inserting some special character like **»é‡æßˆÌæ** to oracle 11g database from java program but in database it will store as **»é¿æß¿Ìæ**.

some characters are replaced like ‡ replaced with ¿.
please advise me what is the correct way to doing this.
thanks in Advance.

Manish

Comment: Are you able to store those problematic characters at all in the DB, i.e. through an another client like SQLDeveloper? What is the character set of the DB?

Comment: Hi Mick, thanks for reply. my database character set is WE8ISO8859P1 and i can't change it to utf-8. that's why i convert my hindi text to these special character and save to database. but as you seen some character are not replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You should select data type UTF8GENERALCI.

Answer (score 0):

Use UTF-8 Encoding for Oracle data types.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your database is set up to use Unicode:

```
select * from nls_database_parameters
   where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

If the answer is `AL32UTF8`, you are fine. If it is something like  `WE8ISO8859P1`, you have a problem. There is no simple solution in that case; you have to set up a new database instance.

Comment: Hi Ammo, thanks for reply. yes my database charset is WE8ISO8859P1 and i can't change it to utf-8. any other way to do the same will be appreciate.

Comment: If you can at least change the table structure, use NVARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR2 for the columns that need unicode support. If this is not possible either, your last option is to somehow encode your string before you write it into the database, and to decode it after reading it back. For example, you could use Base64 encoding or HTML encoding to change those unicode strings into something a ISO8859P1 VARCHAR2 can handle.

Comment: Ammo, thanks for reply. i have tried NVARCHAR2 but same result.i think i have missed something. is there any required  setting for operating system level or when making connection with data base using JDBC.

Comment: Maybe the `NLS_LANGUAGE` environment variable?